minimum number of unique values by row
I have a tibble with 10k rows and 10 columns of different ID strings. I am attempting to write a function similar to dplyr::distinct() which has a min_distinct numeric variable that would be a specified number of columns to be distinct. Almost each row is already distinct (there are a few full duplicates), but I am looking to control specific diversification within the tibble.
Here is a gist example of the data: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NateNohling/b5bd04eda864c135e1bbfa86a09a4295/raw/116f97ef2d2a1bdb0c10d493fceab1166f5a3065/test.csv
So if I run:
data <- readr::read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NateNohling/b5bd04eda864c135e1bbfa86a09a4295/raw/116f97ef2d2a1bdb0c10d493fceab1166f5a3065/test.csv")

filtered_data <- data -> new_function_n_uniques(3)

It would return a filtered tibble with a subset of data that has at least 3 distinct IDs.

Can you please edit this question to include your current code for new_function_n_uniques? Do you know whether the test data you shared actually has any rows which do not meet the requirement of >=3 distinct pos?

I only see 10 values which are distinct within their column, and each appears in a separate row. Does that mean no distinct rows with n>=3 in your definition?  (FWIW I only see 8 values that only appear once in any column.)

Just hacked together something that can go row by row but id need to find a way to iterate it and I dont think its efficient
waldo::compare(slice(data, 1), slice(data, 2)) |>    base::length() - 1
Also, yes I just tested and actually found there is some full duplicates in there so there is definitely rows which do NOT meet the requirement of >= 3 distinct pos
data |>    tibble::rowid_to_column("id_row") |>   janitor::get_dupes(!id_row)

It sounds like we could also state the question as "Keep only the rows whose column-values match at most 7 column-values of any other row." Brute-forcing this involves n(n-1)/2 = 4,999,950,000 comparisons between rows, so it's an intensive calculation. (I'm very curious to see if there are cleverer ways to reframe this to do it faster.)
I load duckplyr so we can use it to make the group-by calculations more efficient. Then I convert the data to long format.
library(tidyverse); library(duckplyr) # I'm using duckplyr 0.3.2
data |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-row) -> df_long
  

I send the long format data to duckplyr's engine, joining it to itself by column and value, so we can find all the matching values within each column. I count how many matches there between each row combination. I exclude self-matches, and then find for each row (row.x) what was the highest degree of matching with any other row. Finally, we keep the rows for which at least 3 rows were distinct from that row's closest match.
df_long |>
  duckplyr::as_duckplyr_df() |>
  left_join(df_long, join_by(name, value)) |>
  summarize(matches = n(), .by = c(row.x, row.y)) |>
  # filter(row.x != row.y) |> # excludes joins where row has no matches at all, ie is.na(row.y)
  filter(row.x != row.y | is.na(row.y)) |> # intended to capture "all unique" rows
  summarize(most_matches = max(matches), .by = row.x) |>
  mutate(distinct = 10 - most_matches) |>
  filter(distinct >= 3)

This runs in about 20 seconds on my machine, which might be adequate for your needs, but can likely be improved upon. Using tidyverse without duckplyr took 40 minutes (120x slower).
I'm seeing 2,535 rows which are "at least 3 distinct from any other row." Rows 1072, 5982, and 1338 are the most distinct, with their closest matches only having 5 values in common (ie 5 are distinct).
# A tibble: 2,535 × 3
   row.x most_matches distinct
   <int>        <int>    <dbl>
 1    11            7        3
 2   180            7        3
 3    22            7        3
 4   364            7        3
 5   387            7        3
 6   244            7        3
 7   280            7        3
 8   298            6        4
 9   401            7        3
10   358            7        3
# ℹ 2,525 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


Original answer, looking at the number of values in each column that are distinct to that row (in this case, not many).
Here's one tidyverse way to count the number of columns in each row which have values which are unique among values in that column.
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-row) |>
  mutate(distinct = n() == 1, .by = c(name, value)) |>
  summarize(dist_count = sum(distinct), .by = row) 

We could then add |> bind_cols(df) to append that to the original data.
Or if we use |> filter(dist_count >= 1) we get ten rows which contain values unique to their columns. None have more than one, but given smaller / more distinct data, you could adjust the logic to dist_count >=3 to get rows with at least 3 unique values (for their column).
# A tibble: 10 × 2
     row dist_count
   <int>      <int>
 1   337          1
 2   577          1
 3  1099          1
 4  2463          1
 5  3637          1
 6  4249          1
 7  5319          1
 8  5717          1
 9  6730          1
10  7084          1


I probably need to reword the question. I think I'm phrasing it confusingly. When I run the code below, I see that data row 1 and data row 2 only have 3 distinct ids between them. So if I run this function and set the min_distinct count to 4, it should filter out this row and move onto the next row to see if theres at least 4 min_distinct IDs and so forth. waldo::compare(slice(data, 1), slice(data, 2))

"it should filter out this row", which row stays, you've compared a pair?

The 1st one, top one, ascending order. Similar to the way the dplyr::distinct(.keep_all = T) logic.

Do you just care about pairs of rows, or adjacent rows, or for each row should it compare to all other rows? If comparing to all rows, are you looking for the minmax -- ie "find the row that is most similar to this one, but only keep the ones where their closest match has at least n differences"?

For each row it should compare to all other rows. So the filtered tibble is diverse. Not only should row 1 and row 2 follow the min_distinct but so should row 1 and 10.

Digging into that answer now, but that looks promising! I wonder if the calculation would be less intensive if it went iteratively somehow, because as you drop rows, you are dropping the set you need to be distinct from. Theoretically by the end you might only have ~ 300 or so rows if the dataset is not very diverse.

For a brute force approach, I'd naively think row 1 needs to be compared to 99,999 other rows, row 2 to 99,998, etc. so if we drop rows as we go that would ultimately avoid half the comparisons. Some help, but I presume a different approach would be needed to find bigger savings.
